# If one loses their job while outside the US, is their worker visa immediately revoked?

Tags: united-states, employment, property, visa, unemployment

Suppose a foreign citizen was working in the US on a non-immigrant worker visa. While they were enjoying their summer break outside the US, they receive an email noting that he had just been terminated. Is their visa void immediately? If so, does this mean that they are locked out of the US and cannot visit their office one last time to pack their stuff?

If no one in the company is willing to send their stuff to their home country, do they lose all rights to their property still stuck in the US? If they were to file a wrongful termination lawsuit, will their visa stay intact until the case is heard and a verdict is reached?

Comment: `If no one in the company is willing to send their stuff to their home country` ask a professional moving company

Answer (score 1):

Your H1b visa is not void, but you cannot use it to enter the US if you are not entering to work for the company that your H1b petition is for. If you need to get your stuff, you can enter as a visitor (either on a B2 visa or on the Visa Waiver Program, if your passport qualifies).

If you do an H1b transfer to another employer, and get the new H1b petition approval, you can use your existing H1b visa and that new H1b petition approval to enter the US to work for that employer. This shows that your visa is still valid, because it can potentially be used in the future.